# Apply css to table td accrording to the data from database

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am using asp.net mvc 3, .net 4.0. One of the td in the table has to have a background colour depending on the data from database. For example, if status is open then yellow, if in progress then green, if closed then blue and so on. 
I would like to write some extension method to do this. But I am clueless about how do I do it. 
If anyone could give an example of doing this it would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you put it in the model associated with the view. So you might have a Boolean property called IsImportant on your model class which makes the table red vs white or something.

Then, in your view (razor?), do like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="@(Model.IsImportant? "important_table" : "normal_table")">
<!-- ... -->
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

with the obvious CSS styles:

```
.important_table
{
  background-color: red;
}

.normal_table
{
  background-color: white;
}
```